# connecting to PostgreSQL from NodeJS not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I've start using NodeJS about a month ago. Since i don't have that much experience running code doesn't always go as want to. In some way i'm not able to connect to my PostgreSQL with node's `pg` package. (Good to know it works when i connect through PDO in PHP)

I have made this (simple) route/controller

```
var pg = require('pg');
var config = require('../config');

module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/db-get-formules', function(req, res) {

    var results = [];

    var pgClient = new pg.Client(config.getDbConnectionString());

    pgClient.connect();

    pgClient.query('SELECT * FROM formules ORDER BY formule_id');

    pgClient.on('row', function(row) {
        results.push(row);
    })

    pgClient.on('end', function() {
        done();
        console.log(results);
        res.json(results);
    })

});

};
```

this is my index.js file in the config:

```
var configValues = require('./config');

module.exports = {

getDbConnectionString: function() {
    return 'postgres://' + configValues.uname + ':' + configValues.password + '@' + configValues.host + ':' + configValues.port + '/' + configValues.database;
}
```

}

In that same config folder i have a config.json file that contains all of the parameters to connect

```
{
  "uname": "username",
  "database": "myDb",
  "host": "localhost",
  "password": "P@ssw0rd",
  "port": "5432",
  "idleTimeoutMillis": "30000"
}
```

If i run this `/db-get-formules` page the page keeps loading (spinning) and nothing really happens. What am i doing wrong?

Oh and just to provide you with my complete code, i have a `server.js` file in the root

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var queryFormules = require('./controllers/queryFormules');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/public/app'));
app.use('/server', express.static(__dirname + '/public/server'));

queryFormules(app);

// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});

app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other answers, and i'm not sure if this will help, but here is how I got it to work:

**config.js**

```
var pg = require('pg');
exports.conString = "pg://user:password@db_address:5432/db_name";
```

**helper.js**

```
var pg = require("pg");
var config = require('../config/config');

exports.runQuery= function(query, next) {
    pg.connect(config.conString, function(err, client) {
        if (err) {
            var e = {
                error: true,
                message: "Unable to connect to database",
                err: err,
            };
            return next(e);
        }

        client.query(query, function(err, result) {
            //deal with the result
            client.end();
            return next(some_data_or_value);
        });
    });
}
```

Then you can call runQuery from anywhere, ofcourse you'll need to deal with the results / possible errors in the function as well.

**some other file or function**

```
var helpers = require('../services/helpers');

var query = "SELECT * FROM formules ORDER BY formule_id"
helpers.runQuery(query, function(result) {
  //deal with results
});
```